# What the difference between `onmessage` and `.addEventListener`?

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I'm trying to get data with server-sent event, what the different using

`source.onmessage` vs `source.addEventListener`?

Answer (score 18):

`source.onmessage` is the built in function wrapper for `EventSource` that is triggered when new data is sent to the client. It fires when **no** `event` attribute is returned (default) and **doesn't** fire when it is set.

`addEventListener` is similar, but differs in that it listens for a specific `event` name, and triggers on its presence, allowing you to separate your functionality for multiple events. You can then parse the JSON data returned. It can be used on any event type. Have a look at this example:

```
source.addEventListener("login", function(e) {
    // do your login specific logic
    var returnedData = JSON.parse(e);
    console.log(returnedData);
}, false);
```

This snippet will listen for a server message with `event` specified as `login`, then it triggers the callback function.

> More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
- http://html5doctor.com/server-sent-events/

Comment: if i'm using the messaging system for web workers, does it matter if I use addEventLisener or onmessage? you mention that addEventListener can be used to listen to multiple events, but isn't that the same thing if you decide to use onmessage vs onclick? you can listen to different events that way too

Comment: Hi @akantoword - I'm not familiar with your application, but if you're sending different event names it's probably clearer and easier to use `addEventListener('myeventname')` to separate your logic. `onmessage` tends to be used more for simple messaging systems where different events are not used. Hope that helps.

Comment: What `event` are you talking about?

Comment: @highmaintenance "event" refers to the first argument in `addEventListener` in this case, not to be confused with the usual javascript `event` objects

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about `addEventListener('message')` vs `onmessage`. They do the same thing, but I'd recommend using `onmessage` because with `addEventListener`, there's always a possibility of unexpectedly adding the same listener twice, e.g. due to a laggy page reload, or some hot-reload during development. In those cases the handler function could fire twice on every event, which leads to weird behaviors.